# Laravel whereIn OR whereIn

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm making a products search by filters:

My code:

```
->where(function($query) use($filter)
{
  if(!empty($filter)){
    foreach ($filter as $key => $value) {           
      $f = explode(",", $value);        
      $query-> whereIn('products.value', $f);
    }           
  }
})
```

Query:

```
and (products.value in (Bomann, PHILIPS) and products.value in (red,white))
```

But I need:

```
and (products.value in (Bomann, PHILIPS) OR products.value in (red,white))
```

Is there something similar in Laravel:

```
orWhereIn
```

Comment: yes and it is exactly called as `orWhereIn`. dude, you should have given it a try 1st.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could have searched just for `whereIn` function in the core to see that. Here you are. This must answer all your questions

```
/**
 * Add a "where in" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  mixed   $values
 * @param  string  $boolean
 * @param  bool    $not
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function whereIn($column, $values, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
{
    $type = $not ? 'NotIn' : 'In';

    // If the value of the where in clause is actually a Closure, we will assume that
    // the developer is using a full sub-select for this "in" statement, and will
    // execute those Closures, then we can re-construct the entire sub-selects.
    if ($values instanceof Closure)
    {
        return $this->whereInSub($column, $values, $boolean, $not);
    }

    $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'column', 'values', 'boolean');

    $this->bindings = array_merge($this->bindings, $values);

    return $this;
}
```

Look that it has a third boolean param. Good luck.

Answer (score 46):

You have a `orWhereIn` function in Laravel. It takes the same parameters as the `whereIn` function.

It's not in the documentation but you can find it in the Laravel API.
See the [Laravel 8 orWhereIn documentation](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIn).

That should give you this:

```
$query-> orWhereIn('products.value', $f);
```

Comment: @HassanAzimi Your comment is wrong and misleading. [link] (https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIn)

Comment: @ofumbi That link doesnt work anymore, and I cant seem to find it anymore: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIn
It's in Database/Query and not Database/Eloquent

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `orWhereIn` is a method that you can use.

I'm fairly sure it should give you the result you're looking for, however, if it doesn't you could simply use `implode` to create a string and then explode it (this is a guess at your array structure):

```
$values = implode(',', array_map(function($value)
{
    return trim($value, ',');
}, $filters));

$query->whereIn('products.value', explode(',' $values));
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$query = DB::table('dms_stakeholder_permissions');
$query->select(DB::raw('group_concat(dms_stakeholder_permissions.fid) as fid'),'dms_stakeholder_permissions.rights');
$query->where('dms_stakeholder_permissions.stakeholder_id','4');
$query->orWhere(function($subquery)  use ($stakeholderId){
            $subquery->where('dms_stakeholder_permissions.stakeholder_id',$stakeholderId);
            $subquery->whereIn('dms_stakeholder_permissions.rights',array('1','2','3'));
    });

 $result = $query->get();

return $result;
```

// OUTPUT @input $stakeholderId = 1

//select group_concat(dms_stakeholder_permissions.fid) as fid, `dms_stakeholder_permissionss`.`rights` from `dms_stakeholder_permissions` where `dms_stakeholder_permissions`.`stakeholder_id` = 4 or (`dms_stakeholder_permissions`.`stakeholder_id` = 1 and `dms_stakeholder_permissions`.`rights` in (1, 2, 3))

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `orWhereIn` where clause method exists in Laravel. Please see the below link of official Laravel Query Builder documentation for detailed information.

Documentation Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses

There are two ways to get the below output.

```
and (products.value in (Bomann, PHILIPS) OR products.value in (red,white))
```

1. Using `orWhereIn`

```
$query = Product::where('color', 'blue')
    ->whereIn('value', ['Bomann', 'PHILIPS'])
    ->orWhereIn('value', ['red', 'white'])
    ->get();
```

Output:

```
select * from `products` where `color` = 'blue' and `value` in (Bomann, PHILIPS) OR `value` in (red,white))
```

2. Using `orWhere` and `whereIn`

```
$query2 = Product::where('color', 'blue')
    ->whereIn('value', ['Bomann', 'PHILIPS'])
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->whereIn('value', ['Bomann', 'PHILIPS']);
    })
    ->get();
```

Output:

```
select * from `products` where `color` = 'blue' and `value` in (Bomann, PHILIPS) OR (`value` in (red,white))
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have multiple whereIn OR whereIn conditions and you want to put brackets, do it like this:

```
$getrecord = DiamondMaster::where('is_delete','0')->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
if(!empty($request->stone_id))
{
    $postdata = $request->stone_id;
    $certi_id =trim($postdata,",");
    $getrecord = $getrecord->whereIn('id',explode(",", $certi_id))
                           ->orWhereIn('Certi_NO',explode(",", $certi_id));     
}
$getrecord = $getrecord->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

**Example 1:** Eloquent Wherein Query Using Laravel Model With Different Column Name

```
public function index()
{
    $data= User::whereIn('name', ['john','dam','smith'])->get();
  
    dd($data);                    
}
```

**Example 2:** Filtering Posts by Categories Using Wherein
Suppose you have a posts table with a category_id column, and you want to retrieve posts from specific categories. You have an array of category IDs you’re targeting:

```
$categoryIds = [2, 4, 6];

$posts = Post::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

**Example  3:** Retrieving Users by IDs using Eloquent Wherein Query
Let’s say you have a users table and you want to retrieve users by their IDs. You have an array of IDs you’re interested in:

```
$userIds = [1, 3, 5, 7];

$users = User::whereIn('id', $userIds)->get();
```

Check here in more detail .
https://woolocker.com/page/how-to-laravel-eloquent-wherein

Comment: If you are affiliated with a linked website, you must disclose your affiliation. Otherwise, your answer could be deleted for spam. Keep in mind that excessively promoting the same website can also get your answers deleted. Please see [how to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).