# Laravel whereIn issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Good day,

I wanted to do something like this:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
$posts = $user->posts()->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

but I get an Internal Server Error. Is there a different way to do this?

For the sake of this example, assume ID is not the primary key and that multiple posts can have the same ID. So this:

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3];
$posts = Post::whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

wouldn't return the desired results.

Comment: What actual error you are getting?

Comment: assuming you meant to write `whereIn('id', $ids)`

Comment: why do you pass arr as parameter instead of $ids ?

Comment: You can also try to do this `$posts = Post::whereIn('id', arr)->toSql();` and check if the query is being build successfully

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel whereIn OR whereIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758819/laravel-wherein-or-wherein)

Comment: Yes, I meant to say $ids. I get the error on the second line of the first code.

Comment: @LukhoMdingi Would you be kind and post the error, please?

Comment: @Sohel0415's answer worked. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having the error is `mysql` is unable to what `table` you are `referring` with `id` column. Use `tableName` in `whereIn()` clouse

```
$posts = $user->posts()->whereIn('posts.id', $ids)->get();
```

**N.B:** I assume your `Post` table name is `posts`

Comment: can somebody explain me why downvoting in this answer?

Comment: This helped. Thank you. I'm not the one who voted down.

Comment: the reason you are having the error is mysql is unable to what table you are referring with id column

Comment: @LukhoMdingi see my updated answer, it will give you clear idea about the problem you are having

Answer (score 0):

please use like

```
  $items = DB::table('items')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

link : [Laravel ->where('id', ARRAY). multiple where conditions laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706603/laravel-whereid-array-multiple-where-conditions-laravel-4?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

And

```
  User::select('id','name','email','phone','created_at')->whereIN('id',[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11])->where('is_guest',NULL)->where('user_type','1')->orderBy('id','desc')->take(20)->get();
```

also work with laravel 5.4

Comment: I didn't get to try this one. @Sohel0415's answer worked. Thank you for your contribution.