# How to write SQL function eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a query like is

```
MODEL::Where(...)
->whereRaw(...)
->get()
```

I want to add my `SQL` function before ->get().

Here, I want to add this raw:

`AND functionX(Id, 1) IN ('1','2','3');`

I try to `whereRaw` but it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use whereIn in laravel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758819/laravel-wherein-or-wherein
see this

Comment: whereIN only works a table I need to run function. How can you write functionX whereIn claus?

Comment: DB::table('users')
             ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
             ->where('status', '<>', 1)
             ->groupBy('status')
             ->get();    try it like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use DB::raw.
For Example :

```
MODEL::Where(...)->where(DB::raw("functionX(Id, 1) IN ('1','2','3')")->get()
```